# JS var in attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
element.append('<div class="' + used_class + '"/>');
```

My javascript knowledge isn't too good.

I've searched for the answer on this question, but found nothing.

Is there a way in JavaScript, to insert `used_class` var with different syntax, preferably a shorter one? Like `#{used_class}` in node.js.

Comment: I'm confused by the question.  Are you trying to dynamically add a class to this particular div?

Comment: @Steve Your example should work, as long as you're remembering the "$" sign (jQuery) and you're not actually using 'element' (unless it is storing a jQuery selector). Am I not seeing something?

Comment: @VoidKing I think he's ascking for a cleaner syntax for what he's doing, not saying it doesn't work

Comment: @ben336 Oh, my apologies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. You could do this though (with jQuery):

```
$('<div/>').appendTo($element).addClass(used_class);
```

or

```
$('<div/>').appendTo($element)[0].className = used_class;
```

- $element can refer to either a DOMElement or jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

few ways to get that using jquery....

try this

```
 element.append($('<div>').attr('class',used_class)); //using attr()
```

or

```
element.append($('<div>').addClass(used_class); //using addClass
```

or

```
element.append($('<div>',{ 'class' : used_class });
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in function similar to python `format` or php `"$var"` syntax, but it's easy to write your own, for example:

```
function format(str, args) {
    return str.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function($0, $1) {
        return args[$1] || ''
    })
}
```

Usage:

```
message = format("{foo} {bar}", {
    foo: 'hello',
    bar: 'world',
}) // "hello world"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no 'shorter' syntax to achieve the desired result, but there are a few better options. For example you can use the [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) function, or [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
$('<div />').addClass(used_class);
$('<div />').prop('class', used_class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine but you can also try this

```
var div = $('<div/>', {
    'class' : used_class,
    'id' : 'someId'
});
$('#anElement').append(div);
```

[**An Example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/A3qjJ/)